# How can I implement "find" command using exec-family?

Tags: c, linux

Im tring to implement ""find . -type f -exec file {} \;" this command by using execvp function.  If I run this in shell, it works well. However when I run this by execvp it keep says >>find: missing argument to `-exec'.

Here is my code

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    char *argv[]={"find", ".", "-type","f","-exec", "file", "{}", "\\;",NULL};
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping rules can be tricky, especially if multiple levels or different contexts are involved :)

`"\\;"` unescapes to `"\;"`. `find` expects its `-exec` args to be terminated by `;`, so you need to pass `";"` directly.

Why not `"\\;"` you might ask? Because `;` has a special meaning in shells. You need to escape it in a shell, because its special meaning needs to be ignored and to have the shell call the command with a literal `;`. When using `execvp`, there's no shell involved, so you don't need to escape the character and pass it verbatim.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    char *argv[]={"find", ".", "-type","f","-exec", "file", "{}", ";",NULL};
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
}
```

If you wanted the same (faulty) behavior and this error message in a shell, you would need to double-escape your exec terminator:

```sh
find . -type f -exec file {} \\\;
```

or

```sh
find . -type f -exec file {} '\;'
```